# Texture becomes black in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders

I downloaded a 3D model from Sketchfab and it looked normal when I rendered it in Eevee. When I switched to Cycles, most of the parts of the texture turned black. From what I read, other people who had this problem had to change some things in the material nodes, but I'm not sure how to do it on these material nodes.

EEVEE render:
[image]

Here's what happens in Cycles:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have time to investigate your mesh closely, but from what I see looking at the image texture and the UV map, there are black parts in the image, and the faces that appear black in your screenshot lie on those black areas in the UV map, and below those faces are other faces that have the green parts... so there is something wrong in the mesh. I guess it doesn't show in Eevee because those black faces have flipped normals, so due to backface culling they are not visible in Eevee. But a raytraced rendered view in Cycles doesn't have backface culling.

Comment: ...if you go into _Edit Mode_, select some of those black faces and hit Alt+N > Flip, then they are black in _Eevee_ as well.

Comment: I see, thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 layers of faces. Your material as it is set will appear black in Cycles because, as Gordon says, the UVs lay on a black part of your image. They will appear transparent in Eevee as the *Material > Settings > Blend Mode* is set to *Alpha Clip*, therefore you'll see the faces behind, that lay on colored parts. It's not clear why it is set this way (maybe a trick to see a black outline), but if you remove the outer faces you'll see the colored faces behind.

To have a black outline you can use this node setup, use an *Iput > Geometry > Backface* as factor between your *Image Texture* and your *Transparent*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ohhh, I see thank you! I didn't realize it was that simple

Comment: Not really, in the UV Map there are faces lying on black areas, that's why they appear black. If you select them and move them aside, they are still black - no Z fighting. But in Eevee the black faces are hidden by backface culling because they have flipped normals.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann, ok I've edited, I guess these 2 faces layers are supposed to create an outline

Comment: @moonboots Oh, I guess you're right about the outline...