# Black boxes appearing on model once i click on the cycles render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Please help fix this, it appears once i do cycles render and not eevee. Im not sure what the difference is.

[image: Black Spots Appearing]

Comment: Check your topology i.e. if all normals are pointing outwards or if you have overlapping polygons.

Comment: I got what you were looking for, might solve your problem https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262814/texture-becomes-black-in-cycles?rq=1

Comment: Maybe overlapping faces (Z-Fighting)? In that case go in Edit mode, select all and press M > Merge by Distance

Comment: Please share a .blend, stripped down to only the object showing the problem, using   https://blend-exchange.com/  .